# What's the best way to configure my Ruby compilation in Debian?

Tags: ruby, installation, debian

When compiling from source, I never know which configure flags to use to optimize the compilation for my environment. Assume the following hardware/OS:

- Single Core, 2 GHz Intel
- 512MB Ram
- Debian 4

I usually just go with

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local`

Should I be doing anything else?

Answer (score 1):

I always use Debian packages. Compiling from sources can break your development environment during libraries conflicts and such problems are hard to detect.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check those few options out, which may be required by a Ruby On Rails environment, in which case they should be compiled. Just make sure the directory corresponds to your current settings.

--with-openssl-dir=/usr --with-readline-dir=/usr --with-zlib-dir=/usr

Answer (score 0):

I recommend mixing in a few packages from Debian Unstable feeds. They tend to be pretty stable, despite the name. They're also very up to date.